# Clone web browser instance

Tags: browser, browser-addons, web

Is there a tool/service that would allow 2 developers to browse the web on separate machines and have dev 1 control dev 2s session and the opposite, without the need for a hardcore remote access like terminal services.

Im thinking etherpad for web browsing

Comment: I found this: but no demo nowhere http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix09/tech/full_papers/yue/yue_html/index.html

Comment: the motivation to do this is .. ?

Comment: im working remotely .. this would be a huge help